# Passing default list argument to dataclasses

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-dataclasses

I would like to pass default argument in my class, 
but somehow I am having problem:

```
from dataclasses import dataclass, field
from typing import List

@dataclass
class Pizza():
    ingredients: List = field(default_factory=['dow', 'tomatoes'])
    meat: str = field(default='chicken')

    def __repr__(self):
        return 'preparing_following_pizza {} {}'.format(self.ingredients, self.meat)
```

If I now try to instantiate `Pizza`, I get the following error:

```
>>> my_order = Pizza()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "pizza.py", line 13, in <module>
    Pizza()
  File "<string>", line 2, in __init__
TypeError: 'list' object is not callable
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I think the problem *may* be because you haven't created an instance of your class

Comment: even with created class instance it does not work..

Comment: No repro. It works perfectly fine with an instance. Please post a [mcve] so we can see what you're doing wrong.

Comment: @Aran-Fey did you try to write the code?  As I said it doesn't work with the an instance, see my edit

Comment: Can you show use your `__init__` method?

Comment: It *does* work with an instance, but you've failed to *create* an instance...

Comment: I dont want to use __init__, the whole point of  @dataclass decorator is that you can skip init

Comment: @Aran-Fey Apparently, dataclasses work differently in 3.6 (external module) and 3.7 (standard module). Which version of Python do you use? I confirm that the OP's code does not work in 3.6.

Comment: @DYZ I'm using 3.7, but I'm pretty sure it doesn't matter. You're right that the code doesn't work in the sense that you get an exception if you call the constructor without arguments; but there's no problem accessing the `ingredients` attribute of a successfully created `Pizza` instance.

Comment: @Aran-Fey But shouldn't the constructor use the default factory when called without the arguments?

Comment: @DYZ Yes, of course, there's a bug in the code. I'm referring to [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52063759/passing-default-argument-to-dataclasses#comment91078267_52063759) - it's simply not true.

Comment: @Aran-Fey When I attempt to create an instance with default parameters: `mypizza=Pizza()` - I get an error message, as described by the OP. Where is the bug? In the module implementation?

Answer (score 203, accepted):

From [the `dataclasses.field` docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html#dataclasses.field):

> The parameters to `field()` are:
>
> - **default_factory:** If provided, **it must be a zero-argument callable** that
>   will be called when a default value is needed for this field. Among
>   other purposes, this can be used to specify fields with mutable
>   default values, as discussed below. It is an error to specify both
>   default and default_factory.

Your `default_factory` is not a 0-argument callable but a list, which is the reason for the error:

```
from dataclasses import dataclass, field
from typing import List

@dataclass
class Pizza():
    ingredients: List = field(default_factory=['dow', 'tomatoes'])  # <- wrong!
```

Use a lambda function instead:

```
@dataclass
class Pizza():
    ingredients: List = field(default_factory=lambda: ['dow', 'tomatoes'])
```

Comment: I get `undefined variable List` and `undefined variable field`

Comment: For furture reference, List and field need to be imported.
`from typing import List`
`from dataclasses import field`

Comment: In this specific case `list` as type hint would be sufficient. No need to import.

Comment: This is terrible. Not your answer, but that the correct answer has to be this convoluted.

Answer (score 26):

For complex datatypes i tend to abbreviate like so:

```
import copy
from dataclasses import dataclass, field
from typing import Dict, Tuple

def default_field(obj):
    return field(default_factory=lambda: copy.copy(obj))

@dataclass
class C:
    complex_attribute: Dict[str, Tuple[int, str]] = default_field({"a": (1, "x"), "b": (1, "y")})
```

Comment: You should also make it `copy.copy(obj)`, otherwise it will be a shared mutable, and that's not a easy thing to debug.

Comment: Yes, this is really bad. Running `c1 = C(); c2 = C(); print("These are exactly the same object: ", id(c1.complex_attribute) == id(c2.complex_attribute))` will give `These are exactly the same object:  True`. Please update this to use `copy.copy()`.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. Is this update, what you mean?

Comment: `copy.deepcopy(obj)` may be used if the values of the dictionary is mutable. In this case it's not since they are tuples.