# How to give a Pydantic list field a default value?

Tags: python, fastapi, python-dataclasses, pydantic

I want to create a Pydantic model in which there is a list field, which left uninitialized has a default value of an empty list. Is there an idiomatic way to do this?

For Python's built-in dataclass objects you can use `field(default_factory=list)`, however in my own experiments this seems to prevent my Pydantic models from being pickled. A naive implementation might be, something like this:

```
from pydantic import BaseModel

class Foo(BaseModel):
    defaulted_list_field: Sequence[str] = [] # Bad!
```

But we all know not to use a mutable value like the empty-list literal as a default.

So what's the correct way to give a Pydantic list-field a default value?

Answer (score 103, accepted):

For pydantic you can use mutable default value, like:

```
class Foo(BaseModel):
    defaulted_list_field: List[str] = []

f1, f2 = Foo(), Foo()
f1.defaulted_list_field.append("hey!")

print(f1) # defaulted_list_field=['hey!']
print(f2) # defaulted_list_field=[]
```

It will be handled correctly (deep copy) and each model instance will have its own empty list.  See "[Fields with non-hashable default values](https://docs.pydantic.dev/latest/concepts/models/#fields-with-non-hashable-default-values)" from the documentation.

---

Pydantic also has `default_factory` [parameter](https://docs.pydantic.dev/latest/concepts/models/#fields-with-dynamic-default-values). In the case of an empty list, the result will be identical, it is rather used when *declaring a field with a default value, you may want it to be dynamic (i.e. different for each model)*.

```
from typing import List
from pydantic import BaseModel, Field
from uuid import UUID, uuid4

class Foo(BaseModel):
    defaulted_list_field: List[str] = Field(default_factory=list)
    uid: UUID = Field(default_factory=uuid4)
```

Comment: "It will be handled correctly (deep copy) and each model instance will have its own empty list." This doesn't seem to be called out in the docs (that I can find) but it really shows off how well-designed `pydantic` actually is.

Comment: Not sure if that chaged or because I'm using pydantic's @dataclass decorator, but I get `ValueError: mutable default <class 'list'> for field defaulted_list_field  is not allowed: use default_factory`

Comment: `@dataclass` does not allow mutable default fields like standard dataclasses.

Comment: There is an example with mutable default in the pydantic docs here: https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/usage/validators/#pre-and-per-item-validators. It uses `List[int] = []`. It does not mention explicitly that it handles the mutable default arg though.

Comment: @kevlarr It appears to be called out in the documentation now: https://docs.pydantic.dev/latest/concepts/models/#fields-with-non-hashable-default-values

Answer (score 13):

While reviewing my colleague's merge request I saw the usage of a mutable object as a default argument and pointed that out. To my surprise, it works as if have done a deepcopy of the object. I found an [example](https://github.com/pydantic/pydantic#a-simple-example) in the project's readme, but without any clarification. And suddenly realized that developers constantly ignore this question for a long time (see links at the bottom).

Indeed, you can write something like this. And expect *correct* behavior:

```
from pydantic import BaseModel

class Foo(BaseModel):
    defaulted_list_field: List[str] = []
```

But what happens underhood?
We need to go deeper...

After a quick search through the source code I found [this](https://github.com/pydantic/pydantic/blob/main/pydantic/fields.py#L438):

```
class ModelField(Representation):
    ...
    def get_default(self) -> Any:
        return smart_deepcopy(self.default) if self.default_factory is None else self.default_factory()
```

While [`smart_deepcopy`](https://github.com/pydantic/pydantic/blob/main/pydantic/utils.py#L677) function is:

```
def smart_deepcopy(obj: Obj) -> Obj:
    """
    Return type as is for immutable built-in types
    Use obj.copy() for built-in empty collections
    Use copy.deepcopy() for non-empty collections and unknown objects
    """

    obj_type = obj.__class__
    if obj_type in IMMUTABLE_NON_COLLECTIONS_TYPES:
        return obj  # fastest case: obj is immutable and not collection therefore will not be copied anyway
    try:
        if not obj and obj_type in BUILTIN_COLLECTIONS:
            # faster way for empty collections, no need to copy its members
            return obj if obj_type is tuple else obj.copy()  # type: ignore  # tuple doesn't have copy method
    except (TypeError, ValueError, RuntimeError):
        # do we really dare to catch ALL errors? Seems a bit risky
        pass

    return deepcopy(obj)  # slowest way when we actually might need a deepcopy
```

Also, as mentioned in the comments you can not use mutable defaults in databases attributes declaration directly (use default_factory instead). So this example [**is not valid**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53632152/why-cant-dataclasses-have-mutable-defaults-in-their-class-attributes-declaratio):

```
from pydantic.dataclasses import dataclass

@dataclass
class Foo:
    bar: list = []
```

And gives:

```
ValueError: mutable default <class 'list'> for field bar is not allowed: use default_factory
```

Links to open discussions (no answers so far):

- [Why isn't mutable default value (field = List[int] = []) a documented feature?](https://github.com/pydantic/pydantic/discussions/3877)
- [How does pydantic.BaseModel handle mutable default args?](https://github.com/pydantic/pydantic/discussions/3274)