# con't define variable in pydantic init function

Tags: python, python-3.x, model, pydantic

i want to define a Base model that inherits from pydantic BaseModel like bellow

```py
class BaseDomain(BaseModel):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self.__exceptions = []

    def add_error(self, exception: GeneralException):
        self.__exceptions.append(exception)
```

but i get this error when i use Product model that inherits from BaseDomain

```
ValueError: "Product" object has no field "_BaseDomain__exceptions"
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Because you have overidden pydantic's **init** method that is executed when a class that inherits from BaseModel is created. you should call super()

```
def __init__(self, **kwargs):
    super().__init__(**kwargs)
    self.__exceptions = []
```

EDIT

It seems that pydantic throws that error because it validates __exceptions as an input and throws an error because it isn't defined in the classes **annotations**

Try this:

```
from typing import List, Any

class BaseDomain(BaseModel):
    __exceptions:List[Any] = []

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
```

Comment: It's a mistake to make mutable arguments on class level:
https://gist.github.com/deniskrumko/4d4d9a6735f723435222116cc0d7f133

Comment: Not an issue when using pydantic @deniskrumko - see https://stackoverflow.com/a/63808835/6560549

Answer (score 3):

Use `PrivateAttr` with default factory:
https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/usage/models/#private-model-attributes

```
from pydantic import BaseModel, PrivateAttr

class MyClass(BaseModel):
    normal_value: int
    __private_value__: Dict[str, int] = PrivateAttr(default_factory=dict)
    _private_list: List = PrivateAttr(default_factory=list)
```

Works both with one underscore or two undescores in names.

Answer (score 0):

Please introduce super in the **init** method.

```py
def __init__(self,**kwargs):
super().__init
```

Comment: This answer could be improved if you explain *why* the super call is necessary. You can use the edit button to provide additional information to your post.

Answer (score 0):

Another version with "underscore_attrs_are_private" option

```
from typing import List, Optional, Any
from pydantic import BaseModel

class BaseDomain(BaseModel):
    __exceptions: Optional[List[Any]] = None
    class Config:
        underscore_attrs_are_private = True

    def add_error(self, exception: Exception):
        if self.__exceptions is None:
            self.__exceptions = []
        self.__exceptions.append(exception)
        
    def get_exceptions(self):
        return self.__exceptions
        
class Item(BaseDomain):
    name: str

item = Item(name="test")
print(item.get_exceptions())
item.add_error(Exception("test"))
print(item.get_exceptions())
```