# What is the difference between an empty default value and default_factory in a dataclass?

Tags: python, data-class

What is the difference between these both dataclass declararions:

```
@dataclass
class Employee:
    Name: str = ""
    Age:  Int = 25
    Family: dict = field(default_factory=dict)
```

and

```
@dataclass
class Employee:
    Name: str = ""
    Age:  Int = 25
    Family: dict = {}
```

In which cases do you need the first over the second?

Comment: It should be a duplicate of this instead: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53632152/why-cant-dataclasses-have-mutable-defaults-in-their-class-attributes-declaratio