# Dataclass - how to have a mutable list as field

Tags: python, python-dataclasses

I want to use the new @dataclass decorator in my code with attribut as mutable list
Something that would look like this

```
from dataclasses import dataclass

@dataclass
class Metrics
    accuracy: list = []
    loss: list = []

...

def do_stuff(data):
    m = Metrics()

    for i in range(0, 10):
        m.accuracy.append(accuracy_def(i))
        m.loss.append(loss_def(i))

    return m
```

But I have this error:

> TypeError: __init__() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'accuracy' and 'loss'

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/52063759/8014793

Comment: Thank ! What's the != between using `list` and `List` from typing ?

Comment: `List` is used for [type hinting](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html) and allows you specify item type within a list like `List[int]` means a list of ints

Answer (score 4):

Use [`dataclasses.field()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html#dataclasses.field) instead

```
@dataclass
class Metrics:
    accuracy: List[int] = field(default_factory=list)
    loss: List[int] = field(default_factory=list)
```