# Using default uuid value in Python dataclasses

Tags: python, python-dataclasses

If I execute the following:

```
@dataclass
class Test:
    hi: Optional[str] = field(
        default_factory=lambda: str(uuid.uuid1()))

@dataclass
class Test2:
    hi: Optional[str] = str(uuid.uuid1())

if __name__ == "__main__":
    a = Test() # Test(hi='115a865c-33be-11eb-94a1-34c93db23648')
    b = Test() # Test(hi='115a865d-33be-11eb-8c6f-34c93db23648')
    c = Test2() # Test2(hi='10e44300-33be-11eb-85eb-34c93db23648')
    d = Test2() # Test2(hi='10e44300-33be-11eb-85eb-34c93db23648')
```

Why `Test` will return for every instance a different uuid, while `Test2` will return the same each time?

Also, why `default factory` is needed and not `default`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Passing default list argument to dataclasses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52063759/passing-default-list-argument-to-dataclasses)

Comment: @TomWojcik No, I saw that but didn't understand how it answers my use case TBH

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As stated in the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html#dataclasses.field)

> default_factory: If provided, it must be a zero-argument callable that
> will be called when a default value is needed for this field. Among
> other purposes, this can be used to specify fields with mutable
> default values, as discussed below. It is an error to specify both
> default and default_factory.

In your first example

```
@dataclass
class Test:
    hi: Optional[str] = field(
        default_factory=lambda: str(uuid.uuid1()))
```

you pass an anonymous function to the default factory.

To make things easier, lets make a non anonymous function.

```
def get_new_uuid() -> str:
    return str(uuid.uuid1())


@dataclass
class Test:
    hi: Optional[uuid.UUID] = field(default_factory=get_new_uuid)
```

so each instance of `Test` calls `get_new_uuid` function to obtain new uuid, when initialized.

---

Your second example assigns a default value.

```
@dataclass
class Test2:
    hi: Optional[str] = str(uuid.uuid1())
```

It's an equivalent of this

```
@dataclass
class Test2:
    hi: Optional[str] = field(default=str(uuid.uuid1()))
```

As you can see, here `default` parameter is used, while previously it was `default_factory`. Here, you don't pass a function, but a value. It's a one-time thing.

In `Test` you can't access `hi` without instantiating it.
But `Test2` has default value assigned on import, so you can access it without instantiating. It's similar to class attribute and instance attribute defined in `__init__`.

Comment: "In Test you can't access hi without instantiating it. But Test2 has default value assigned on import, so you can access it without instantiating. It's similar to class attribute and instance attribute defined in __init__."
That's the difference I looked for. Thanks!